# Posting GeoJSON with DRF causes "function st_geomfromewkb(bytea) does not exist"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postgis, geojson, django-rest-framework-gis

I set up a Django Rest Framework (DRF) API using [django-rest-framework-gis](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis).

It works fine to post data from the API's interface, as long as I keep the geometry field to `null`.
But as soon as I try including a GeoJSON in the `geometry` field (as below)...

```
{
    "gmlid": "this is a test from DRF interface",
    "name": "",
    "envelope": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 5.000000, 23.000000 ] },
    "creation_date": null,
    "xml_source": ""
}
```

...I get the following error:

> ProgrammingError at /en/api/cityobject/
>
> function st_geomfromewkb(bytea) does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...atest_from_browser', '', '', '', '', ST_Transform(ST_GeomFro...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.
>
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/api/cityobject/ Django Version:    2.2
>   Exception Type:   ProgrammingError Exception Value:
>
> function st_geomfromewkb(bytea) does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...atest_from_browser', '', '', '', '', ST_Transform(ST_GeomFro...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.
>
> Exception Location:
>     /home/me/dj-workspace/my-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py
>   in _execute, line 84 Python Executable:
>     /home/me/dj-workspace/my-venv/bin/python Python Version:    3.6.8
>   Python Path:
>
> ['/home/me/dj-workspace/myapp',  '/usr/lib/python36.zip', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.6',  '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
>   '/home/me/dj-workspace/my-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>
> Server time:  Sat, 5 Oct 2019 07:49:35 +0000

What may be causing this error?

---

My code looks like this:

models.py

```
class Cityobject(models.Model):
    gmlid = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    envelope = models.GeometryField(blank=True, null=True, srid=2056)  
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    xml_source = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name - {0} -- GML ID - {1}".format(self.name, self.gmlid) 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cityobject'
```

views.py

```
class CityobjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Cityobject information to be viewed or edited.
    """    
    lookup_field = 'id' 
    queryset = Cityobject.objects.all()  
    serializer_class = CityobjectSerializer
    filter_fields = ('id','gmlid','name',)
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'cityobject', views.CityobjectViewSet, 'cityobject')
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

serializers.py

```
class CityobjectSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cityobject
        fields = (
                    "gmlid",
                    "name",
                    "envelope",
                    "creation_date",
                    "xml_source"
            )    
        geo_field = 'envelope'
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': 
            {
            },       
    'citydb': 
            {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', 
            'OPTIONS': {
                            'options': '-c search_path=citydb'
                        },
            'NAME': 'db_dev',
            'USER': secrets.USER,
            'PASSWORD': secrets.PASSWORD,
            'HOST': 'my.host.com',
            'PORT': '5432',
            },

}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation', #must be before django.contrib.admin
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'main_app',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_gis',
    'django_filters',
    'leaflet',
     ...
]
```

Comment: Just curious, you have 2 databases there, not just 1.  Is it possible you are using the wrong one?   You could add a `.using('citydb')` to your `queryset` in your `ViewSet`.  Also have you run the full syncdb and installed the correct extension (if its not already there).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBacker, but this apparently isn't the issue. I setup a DB router to route the models to `'citydb'` and also tried adding `.using('citydb')` but that didn't help. I don't think `syncdb` will help, since the model is `managed = False`.

Comment: One new element is I found the PostGIS geometry column type is `Polygon`, not `Point`. But when I provide a Polygon geojson (e.g. `"envelope": {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[4.0,4.0],[4.0,1.0],[1.0,4.0],[4.0,4.0]]}`), then DRF shows this new error: 

`HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
{
    "envelope": [
        "Unable to convert to python object: Invalid geometry pointer returned from \"OGR_G_CreateGeometryFromJson\"."
    ]
}`

Do you by chance see any other explanations based on this, @AndrewBacker?